# Merge words from a specific column into a row when other columns values are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

| user | friend | food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mary | alex | fries |
| mary | eric | fries |

How do I get the following dataframe

| user | friend | food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mary | alex eric | fries |

Comment: ```df.groupby(['user'])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need join only unique values per `user`, then aggregate lambda function:

```
df = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.unique()))
```